# PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: syntax error at or near "PARALLEL"

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

i am not able to create this extension "hstore".

rails version: 5

osx version: 10.12.6

when i type this command "postgres -V" it returns:

```
postgres (PostgreSQL) 10.1
```

complete error log is:

```
bilals-MacBook-Pro-2:testapp bilalbasharat$ bundle exec rails db:setup
Database 'testapp_development' already exists
Database 'testapp_test' already exists
-- enable_extension("plpgsql")
   -> 0.0196s
-- enable_extension("hstore")
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error         at or near "PARALLEL"
: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "hstore"
```

Comment: Where did you define SQL statement? As far as I know, you need to have a column added to the DB table. I'm referring to [this](https://nandovieira.com/using-postgresql-and-hstore-with-rails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my os to "macOS high sierra" . in a fresh OS i setup the rails app starting from brew , than installing postgres , than node and than setup rails app. than when i ran "bundle exec rails db:setup" it fixed and project ran just fine.

this is not an actual solution. it is time consuming. but it worked.